# IE not parsing HTML correctly

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dom

Here's a snapshot of my HTML code as viewed **after clicking View Source in IE9**. I opens up in Notepad++

[image: Snapshot of my HTML code]

Here is the code as parsed by the IE9's Developer Tool:

[image]

Why is there a disconnect between the two?

Comment: You mean that most of the `<head>` content ends up in the body? Hm. Can you make the source available somewhere?

Comment: Does your HTML [validate](http://validator.w3.org/)? I understand that you blanked out parts for privacy reasons, but without seeing the whole thing (actual code) it's impossible to say **if** there's anything wrong with it. Chances are *very* low of "IE not parsing HTML correctly".

Comment: Yes. It looks OK to the naked eye, but the fact that IE changes the DOCTYPE declaration into a comment, proves that there's something wrong with the document. Something that we can't see.

Comment: There might be a fancy hidden character right before the DOCTYPE declaration that mess things up - seen it happening to many people. View the file with Hex Editor to verify it and remove that character.

Comment: What Shadow Wizard said. Seen this happen when a document ends up with two BOMs at the start. The first BOM is interpreted correctly, the second BOM as an invisible character that makes the parser think the body has started.

Comment: In NP++: Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8 without BOM, then save and upload

Comment: @Madmartigan I'd say that deserves to be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @MrLister: It's merely speculation at this point. We can't rule out the HTML code itself without actually seeing it. Feel free to post it as an answer yourself if you wish, I've actually voted to close based on not enough information.

Comment: Yes, more info needed from the OP. But if I were to vote to close, it would be for "too localised". This is not a problem that pops up often.

Comment: @Madmartigan - Bit harsh to close I think. It's almost impossible to know what to post without knowing what the correct answer is. As it happens, only a link to the actual page, or a hex dump of the page would show the problem. This is quite a common question. I've seen it on SO at least 3 times before, but it's probably hard to know what good search terms are.

Comment: @Alochi: If sample code was posted, we can validate it, then test it with and without BOM and know the answer, but no code was posted. Can't copy/paste a screen shot. Obviously these things could be ruled out beforehand by the OP in the process of producing a minimal test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Shadow Wizard suggested in a comment, the probable cause is some data character before the `<!DOCTYPE ...>` declaration. For example, the problem is reproducible by taking a valid XHTML document and inserting the no-break space character (NBSP, U+00A0) at the very start of the document. But the presence of a BOM at the start does *not* cause the problem (at least not on IE 9, hardly on any browser in use). There is a large number of invisible or barely visible characters that might cause the problem.

Comment: UTF-8 without BOM encoding fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

The Developer Tool does NOT show you the source of your code, it shows the DOM (Document Object Model) that's why there are differences. You can read more about DOM here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/

The content showed in Developer Tool represents your parsed Source with some modifications to be more readable and without incorrect tags, in two words it does not show the exact source.

Comment: The first screenshot shows exactly that source. It was opened up in Notepad++ after I click View Source.

Comment: Although what you say is correct @micnic, that IE console output is really not normal. Look at where it's showing the doctype for instance.